# How to start migration with migrate module

Tags: 6, importing-exporting, migrations

I'm trying to make the [migrate module](http://drupal.org/project/migrate) to work, but I can't find where the dashboard is located.

In this url: www.foo.com/admin/content/migrate

I have the list of all available content that can be migrated into the DB (screenshot below).

However there must be another screen where you can actually initiate the import process.

I've tried this other url: www.foo.com/admin/content/migrate/dashboard

But it gives a 404 page not found error.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is the Migrate UI module active? If yes, please try to clear the menu cache.